# VBA Randomly generated strings repeating - why?

Tags: excel, vba, random

I have created a VBA function which will produce a randomly generated string of the format XX00XXX. I ran this to create in excess of 400000 serials in an excel spreadsheet, however there are an abnormally high number of repititions of the same string; over 60% of the strings have more than one instance (>250 in some cases!). I would expect some repitition but nowhere near this level. Is there a problem with my code? Or perhaps this is my week to play the lottery.

```
Function NewVRN() As String

Dim strOne As String
Dim strTwo As String
Dim strThree As String
Dim strFour As String
Dim strFive As String
Dim strSix As String
Dim strSeven As String



' Initialize the seed using Timer.
    Randomize 

'Generate random letters
    strOne = Chr(Int((90 - 65 + 1) * Rnd) + 65)
    Randomize
    strTwo = Chr(Int((90 - 65 + 1) * Rnd) + 65)
    Randomize
    strFive = Chr(Int((90 - 65 + 1) * Rnd) + 65)
    Randomize
    strSix = Chr(Int((90 - 65 + 1) * Rnd) + 65)
    Randomize
    strSeven = Chr(Int((90 - 65 + 1) * Rnd) + 65)
    Randomize

'Generate random numbers
    strThree = Chr(Int((57 - 48 + 1) * Rnd) + 48)
    Randomize
    strFour = Chr(Int((57 - 48 + 1) * Rnd) + 48)


'Concatenate and build the VRN
        NewVRN = strOne & strTwo & strThree & strFour & strFive & strSix & strSeven

 End Function
```

The function is called as part of a Sub which first does some other 'stuff' and then (at the point of calling the function) simply writes the result into a cell and selects the next cell. It does this in quick succession with no other operations between. As far as I can see, serials are not generally repeated on the next call.

I've had a look at some of the other solutions on here but none seem to answer this specific problem. It is accepted that there are limitations with the RNG in office but i think the observation here is quite extreme. There is also a problem with modern processors (with several calcultions per timer interval) but the randomize statements and the independent execution of the function should have resolved this.

P.S. I ideally wanted a mostly unique list of random serials - with the acceptance that probability would mean there would be a minimal number of repeats. In the end I just created a loop which would add one to the sequence each time (ie AA00AAA, AA00AAB etc). I would still like to know why my random generator is not working!

Comment: There is also a solution in the public domain which creates an array of unique random numbers. Given that I am working with unordered strings and fairly high volumes, I don't think it would be practical to compare the generated string to the list of previous stings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to call `Randomize` once, at the beginning of your program.

Each time you call `Randomize` (without specifying a seed) VB is using the system timer to set which Random number to use next.

Call `Randomize` in quick succession and you run the risk of VB using the same Random number, which is what you've observed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out. The reason I `randomized` each time was because I read that following the initial seed, the RNG follows a fixed sequence using the previous computation of `rnd` as the seed. Having read this I wanted to avoid the situation where I could get a lot of AA00AFH GG66PHH.

Comment: Based on a sample of 100,000 repititions, this appears to have resolved it, thanks. Comparing 100,000 repitions using my original code, resulted in just under 10% being duplicated at some point. Modifying the code as suggested resulted in zero repeats.

Comment: @RandomDave what you've read is correct it is a fixed sequence but that sequence is random (pseudo) and very very long. Randomize sets where in that sequence we get the next RND number and each time we call RND we move to the next number in the sequence.